# Using Filter Function to Return React Component - Code Review

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I dont understand what I am doing wrong here. I am using `Immutable.js` & `React` in my app. I am calling Immutable.js's `filter` function to refine the collection based on the `if` condition & return array of React components.

Its actually return 'svgTemplateState' instead of the React component collection.

```
        let getUpdatedTem = ( renderType, svgTemplateState ) => {
            switch( renderType ){
            case( "Template Selection" ):
                return( svgTemplateState.filter(( templateType ) => {
                    if( templateType.get( "templateNo" ) > -1 ){
                        let temType = templateType.get( "type" );
                        return(
                            <TemplatePath
                             temData = { templateType }
                             key = { temType } />
                        );
                    }
                }));
            case( "Preview" ):
...
```

Comment: It's normal you filter your list to have another list of all element that match the predicate

Comment: The list being returned is the same as 'svgTemplateState' array, when I expect it to return `TemplatePath` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immutable filters should return a boolean, indicating whether or not you want the template to be a part of the collection that you are returning. In your case, you're returning a React component.

You're iterating `svgTemplateState`, which appears to be a Map (it's not entirely clear to me what it is). What you should be iterating is a collection of templates, and check the template number on each template within the collection. You'd have something (simplified) like:

```
let newCollection = templatesCollection.filter( template => template.get( "id" ) > -1);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I didnt even know that its boolean return. Thank you, this immediately resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you want to find the first Item that match the condition? like .[findEntry](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/findEntry)() ?

Comment: Then if found return the component?

Comment: Thanks Michael for the help and the effort, however, I want to filter through the collection. Gratefully, Kim resolved the issue. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
            return( svgTemplateState.filter(( templateType ) => {
                if( templateType.get( "templateNo" ) > -1 ){
                    let temType = templateType.get( "type" );
                    return(
                        <TemplatePath
                         temData = { templateType }
                         key = { temType } />
                    );
                }
            }));
```

Assuming svgTemplateState is an array, replace the "filter" method in the above code with "map". If svgTemplateState is an object with  pairs then use a for...in to iterate over svgTemplateState, check the condition and push the  component to a temp object which you can return after the loop.